# Как можно реализовать второй порт для Веб приложения?

Tags: nginx

Заголовок странный и непонятный, поэтому я постараюсь описать его суть.

Есть некоторый сервис, который может работать только с адресом вида `IP:PORT`. Если прописать домен (например: https://my.site.com/api), то этот сервис будет ругаться, мол, не указан порт. Такой вариант тоже не работает: https://my.site.com:443/api.

По адресу https://my.site.com находится Rails приложение.

Отсюда следующий вопрос - как лучше реализовать это через nginx, какой командой?

Comment: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen

Comment: @nörbörnën то есть в nginx конфиге rails приложения, где идет прослушка 80 и 443 портов, мне нужно прописать еще и свой третий?

Comment: да. или попробовать сказать сервису не `https://my.site.com:433/api`, а `https://my.site.com:443/api`, или сказать сервису `http://my.site.com:80/api`, или вообще разобраться почему сервис не хочет понимать `https://my.site.com:433/api`

Comment: @nörbörnën `433` - это опечатка была. А с `http` сразу редирект на `https` идет.